# Hydra - Attacking when login page encodes the username and password

Tags: encoding, hydra

I needed to test how Hydra works, so I tried to attack my own wifi router. I set the user name as "user" and created a txt file containing 100 passwords including the "real" password.

I am unable to read the log in of the http request that contains the ^USER^ and ^PASS^ because it uses a hashing method and passes the request as an encoded string.

Here, is what I found:

`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.`

Here is a screenshot;
[image]

And I inspected `main.js` file of that website, and realized that there are some  hashing methods used;

```
if(g_password_type == '4') {
psd = base64encode(SHA256(name + base64encode(SHA256($('#password').val())) + g_requestVerificationToken[0]));
} else {
psd = base64encode($('#password').val());
}
```

In such a case, how can we bruteforce the username and password?

Is there a way in hydra to point out "this" is the password field and "this" is the username text and test when "this" log in button is pressed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the code clearly indicates, the name, password, and verification token are hashed together before being sent over the network. So, no, you cannot figure out which is which just from the network data alone.

Hydra is not the tool that is going to work for you here. You need to come up with a way of sending `psd` with all that data formatted in the expected way (combined, hashed, and encoded).

Comment: If hydra not works here, how should I start?

Comment: You will need to create a script that does hydra's work for you and send the data in the way that the server expects.

Comment: Actually I don't have any understanding about how should I create such a script. What field I should learn to accomplish my task. Can you suggest me how should I start?

Comment: The javascript code tells you exactly what to do - you just need to replicate that in your script and feed it a list of usernames and passwords.

Comment: Can I use my own code and send the website data as we sends in normal GUI.

Comment: Yes. That's what hydra does. If you do not know how to script, then you are now beyond the scope of this site. You will have to learn how to program. Look at Python as a beginner language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78721/discussion-between-tharindu-and-schroeder).